# SSRS Globals!RenderFormat.Name hide textbox when printing

Tags: excel, reporting-services, printing, report

When viewing my report on the report server the headers roll with the report. To enable something similar in Excel I created textboxes above the tablix, not in the tablix.

Using `IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)` in the header's cell under Visibility - Hidden prevents the tablix header from appearing when the report is exported to Excel.

Using `=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` in the textbox above the tablix under Visibility - Hidden prevents the textbox from appearing when the report is viewed on the report server.

However, what do I do to prevent both the text boxes above the tablix and the tablix headers appearing when I print?

Comment: And the double-headers are only on the first page. Every page after that have just the tablix headers when printed.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2010/05/02/globalsrenderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout/. Reporting Services built-in rendering extension names include: “WORD“, “EXCEL“, “PDF“, “MHTML“, “IMAGE” (includes TIFF, Print). Note that interactive viewing in preview or report manager uses the “RPL” renderer.